# How to use "who" vs. "that"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, who-that

I often get confused when trying to use who vs that.

Some examples that often confuse me:

#### *That*

> The person that went to the store.
>
> The people that went shopping.
>
> The persons that went shopping.
>
> The group that went shopping.

#### *Who*

> The person who went to the store.
>
> The people who go shopping.

Please explain when to use either for plural subjects and singular subjects.  Animate and inanimate objects as well.

Comment: Related: [Should you use "who" or "that" when talking about multiple people doing something?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427/should-you-use-who-or-that-when-talking-about-multiple-people-doing-something)

Comment: I agree that it's grating to hear people referenced with a "that." It is depersonalizing, while who is a manifestation of human solidarity. If we must scrub our prose of cuss-words (something I've come somewhat reluctantly to support) referencing people with a who makes a good counter-rule. In my own work, I sort of make "that" a word to avoid. One good way around the overall awkwardness of, "Doctors and Hospitals who/that accept Medicare patients" is the gerund, "Doctors and hospitals accepting Medicare patients."
As for the myriad precedents in which respected authors have used a "that."if t

Comment: The, "Accepting Medicare patients..." above should have been called a gerundIVE, because it's the key to a phrase that functions as an adjectIVE.  I know some real grammarians are looking at this forum, and wanted to fix my nomenclature before anyone called me on it!  The only real rule 'bout optimum expression is, "It depends on the situation." Part of the situation is available vocabulary.  Another way around would be, "Providers who..."

Comment: All the rules are 'made up'. It's following them that keeps the language meaningful.

Comment: One rule I've always been taught (and MS Word seems to reinforce this whenever I forget) is that phrases beginning with "**who**" tend to be dependent clauses that require a comma before and after, whereas with "**that**" phrases, you can just go right into it without a comma for pause.

Comment: I was told that American English uses *who* and *which* for descriptive/non-defining clauses and *that* for defining clauses. I think that is good guidance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is usually said that *who* is used for people (and sometimes animals) while *that* is used to refer to objects.

In actual usage, though, both *who* and *that* can be used to refer to persons, sometimes to animals, and sometimes to entities that consist of people.

- The dog who/that chewed the bone chased the cat.
- The person who/that stole my purse used all my credit cards.
- The group who/that went shopping was mugged.

*That*, not *who*, is used to refer to objects.

- The house that Jack built is falling down.

Here's what [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0856500#m_en_gb0856500) says:

> It is sometimes argued that, in relative clauses, *that* should be used for non-human references, while *who* should be used for human references: *a house that overlooks the park* but *the woman who lives next door*. In practice, while it is true to say that *who* is restricted to human references, the function of *that* is flexible. It has been used for human and non-human references since at least the 11th century, and is invaluable where both a person and a thing is being referred to, as in *a person or thing that is believed to bring bad luck*.

For  more examples of actual usage, here's a link to [Merriam Webster's Dictionary of English usage](http://books.google.com/books?id=2yJusP0vrdgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) (see pages 895 and 896).

Comment: So in other words, are they pretty much interchangeable?

Comment: It's more that "that" can be used basically anywhere, and therefore can replace "who." You could say it is the default term. Whereas "who" can only be used with animate referents.

Comment: @MAA: I wouldn't say, "Jack, that is my friend's husband, just got a job in Mumbai." When I'm speaking of a specific person whose identity is known, I'd prefer _who_ to _that_. Contrast this with "The person that sent this email should confess."

Comment: I agree that in your example using "that" with Jack is odd sounding, but I think that may have more to do with the specific type of relative clause used - you could, for example say parenthetically: "Jack (that's my friend's husband) just got a job in Mumbai." Or in casual conversation you could definitely hear "I invited my friend Jack that lives up the street," even if it might LOOK funny when reading it. Maybe in your example "that" doesn't work because the relative clause breaks up the main clause.

Comment: I would also say "Jack that's my friend's husband" if I was distinguishing that Jack from another Jack I know. For example, if I was talking to a friend and we knew several Jacks, I might say "Jack that has the Great Dane just got a job in Mumbai." In that case the difference is reference to known information, rather than the introduction of new information, so maybe there's a key in there somewhere.

Comment: It does sound perfectly all right to use "that" for people in restrictive clauses (like in your example of distinguishing one Jack from another). Interesting point.

Answer (score 3):

The relative pronoun "that" used in reference to a person or to people has been extant since at the 11th century (I lack proper citation for this date, but there are ample instances throughout 13th and 14th century literature - notably in Chaucer)  but is typically only employed when a pronoun is used to combine both a person or people and a thing or things simultaneously.

Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary, 11th Edition and American Heritage Dictionary both note the interchangeability of "who" and "that" with either being acceptable when referring to a person or to people, however.

(See citations listed with [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20210411005812/https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-versus-that).)

According to [GrammarBook](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoVwhVt.asp), there are three basic rules:

1. *Who* refers to people. *That* and *which* refer to groups or things.
2. *That* introduces essential clauses while *which* introduces nonessential clauses.
3. If *this*, *that*, *these*, or *those* has already introduced an essential clause, you may use *which* to introduce the next clause, whether it is essential or nonessential.

These are the rules as were drilled into my head by both my family and throughout my education.  As a matter of personal preference, I would like to add that I find the casual use of *that* in reference to a person or people to be revealing.  To equate someone to a thing is to depersonalize - even when one is referring to one's self.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why people think that "that" means "thing". After all, we happily say things like "that man" (we have no choice, in fact!). It seems like a silly rule someone in the 19th century came up with to create some parallel to the gender-based system in Latin. Additionally, "that" probably isn't even a pronoun in this construction, but a complementizer of the same type seen in statements like "I believe that..." and "he said that...".

Comment: @siride "that" in "that man" is an adjective.  In "the man that", it's a conjunction.

Comment: @NeilG: yes, I am aware. I'm speaking to the reasoning behind the supposed rule that you aren't supposed to use "that" as a conjunction when the referent is a person. Note the last paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any difference for plural and singular subjects; the difference is for people and non-people.  Saying *who* is personifying, saying *that* or *which* is objectifying.

Presumably one should always say *who* when speaking of a human being, or other entity known to be of roughly equivalent or higher intelligence, and *that* or *which* when speaking of an inanimate object.  Animals and other beings thought to be of below-human cognitive capacity are something of a gray area; I'd say choose your usage according to what sort of tone you want to convey.

Comment: What do you mean by gray area?  There is no definite rule?

Comment: @subt13: Yes.  I believe one can get away with either usage in reference to animals, and the choice one makes will affect the tone of the work.

Comment: _That_ is used instead of _who_, _whom_, and _which_; there is not rule in English grammar that says _that_ should not be used for persons. In fact, the dictionary reports you can replace _who_ with _that_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: "The dictionary"?  Surely you know there is no singular "the dictionary".  For a contrary viewpoint to whatever work you're referring to, try http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoVwhVt.asp.

Comment: The _New Oxford American Dictionary_ and dictionary.com report what I wrote. In the _Corpus of Contemporary English_ you can find sentences like _Remember the person that was that clever to do that_?

Comment: Well, you both can't be right :)...

Comment: @subt13: Part of the situation appears to be "sources disagree".

Comment: @chaos: Good lord. Ms Straus, grammarbook.com/grammar/whoVwhVt.asp offers up three rules for relative pronoun use and they are either wrong or badly misleading. 'which', as *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* notes, is also used in certain limited situations when the referent is people.

Answer (score 0):

When I was at the U of Oregon in the 1970s studying journalism, the AP style guide required the word "who" when referring to people and "that" when referring to anything non human, whether an inanimate carbon rod, or a dog. It grates on my ears to hear so many people use "that" when referring to a person. I agree that it shows the increasing depersonalization of society. It seems that these days, people are just objects, not human beings, and the language is reflecting that.

Comment: Oh, so we, the Dutch-speakers, have always lived in a depersonalised society. :P

Comment: There's nothing depersonalizing about "that", any more than "that man" is depersonalizing. Someone made up a rule that "who" goes with people and "that" doesn't, which had no basis in the history of the language or its syntax, and now we have people like you trying to make commentary about a whole society based on the words used in relative clause. Get a grip!

Answer (score 0):

**Who**, **which** and **that** can go after **singular nouns** or **plural nouns**.

**Who** refers to people - The *person* who went, The *people* who went

**Which** refers to things/**inanimate objects** -The letter which came, The letters which came

'**That**' can be used instead of who or which. - The person that, the letter that, the letters that

With people, who is more usual and with things that is more usual.