# who vs that as a pronoun

Tags: differences, pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use: who/that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/how-to-use-who-that)

I have seen many writers using *"that"* as a pronoun in cases where *"who"* should be used. For example, a book author says

I apologize to those of you ***that*** are unable to obtain electronic copies.

Should it not be

I apologize to those of you ***who*** are unable to obtain electronic copies.

Or is it wrong to use the latter, in the modern context?

Answer (score 1):

Well, why "should" *who* be used if English speakers often choose *that*? What's the reason behind your premise in the first place?