# Should I use 'that' 'which' or 'who' in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, which-who

> Boys don't play    with dolls    **that**
>   they know    for a long time,    unless
>   they see another boys
>       playing with them.

Well it means that boys sometimes boys are not interested in a girl they know for a while until they discover the girl has someone.

In this sentence, dolls is a symbol for girls. I'm a bit confused if I should use **that**, **which** or **who**?

(by the way, should use **'until'** instead of **'unless'**?)

Comment: a doll is a thing. I would use which. Also use `have known`, also `other boys or another boy. Not another boys`

Comment: @mplungjan can you give an answer do that I can tick it.

Comment: Partially related: [When is it appropriate to use 'that' as opposed to 'which'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-that-as-opposed-to-which), [How to use "who" vs "that"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/how-to-use-who-that)

Comment: @janoChen: don't be in a rush to tick the first answer you get within a few minutes. Leave the question open for a day or two, then you will usually get more and better answers. Wait until no further answers seem to be immediately forthcoming. (Oh, and this is not meant as an offense to mplungjan. (^_^))

Comment: I am offended, @Reg. Very ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use *that* where it refers to an object, and is a restrictive clause (meaning, if you left the word out of the sentence, the meaning of the sentence would change):

> I want the hat that has the giant flower in the band.

Use *which* where it refers to an object, and is a non-restrictive clause (meaning, if you left the word out of the sentence, the meaning of the sentence wouldn't change):

> I have a lovely new hat, which has a giant flower in the band.

Use *who* where you are referring to a person:

> I saw a lady who was wearing a lovely new hat.

I'm having trouble answering your question more directly, because I can't really understand your sentence. I'm not sure whether you are referring to dolls in the sense of toys (in which case you should use *that* because "know for a long time" is a restrictive clause), or in the slang sense for women (in which case it should be *who*, and I would probably recommend that you find a less sexist term!).

Comment: @Loquacity it is not a slang, it is a symbol (or metaphor?).

Comment: @janoChen A metaphor? So you are saying that women resemble playthings?

Comment: @Loquacity I mean not in a bad sense. More like playing in the game of seduction.

Comment: @janoChen The 'game of seduction' still portrays men as the hunter and women as the hunted. Even if you disregard all the sexist ways the term 'doll' has been used to refer to women for generations, it is still offensive. I strongly recommend you find a new term.

Comment: @Loquacity I'm very far from being a sexist (towards women). I even think that women are superior than men. But I think you are right, I will look for another word.

Comment: @janoChen I haven't accused you of being sexist, just suggested that you choose appropriate words. Thank you for taking my advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

Boys don't play with girls they have known for a long time, unless they see other boys playing with them.