# "People who" vs "people which"

Tags: pronouns, which-who

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use 'that' 'which' or 'who' in this sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24218/should-i-use-that-which-or-who-in-this-sentence)

Should I use "who" or "which"? I'm leaning to "who", but I'm not sure...

> If you're not one the people who already made their mind up about

or

> If you're not one the people which already made their mind up about

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
people => who/that
things => which/that
```

> The boy who/that stole my car.
>
> The car which/that was stolen by this boy.

Comment: Yes, as far as it goes. But both sentences are ungrammatical as they stand; indeed, they're not obviously sentences at all. Something is missing. Put back the rest of the clause markers. Are you one of the people? Or are the people only other people? Have you made up your mind about them? Have they made up their mind(s) about you? What in the world is being supposed (as the clausal object of _If_)?

Comment: Well, the Anglican version of the Lord's Prayer plays fast and loose with this point of view: "Our Father, **which art in heaven**, hallowed be thy name; thy kingdom come; thy will be done, in earth as it is in heaven."

Comment: Additionally, I've heard it further explained that "which" is indeterminate whereas "that" is determinate.