# Multiple objects + relative clause

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses

Which would be best / acceptable?

"He saw people, animals and buildings THAT / WHICH had suffered greatly."

As I see it, there are 3 subjects; people, animals and buildings. The grammar rules I know state we must use "who + people" "which + things", etc. And because it is a defining relative clause, I can also use "that".

So do the mixed subjects (people and things) mean I have to use "that" in this sentence, due to the fact we don't use "which" for people?

Comment: They're not subjects; they're direct objects of _saw_.  And there ought to be a comma after _animals_ if you're writing it. Other than that, either _which_ or _that_ will work. In cases where either is allowed, _which_ is slightly more formal because it's more unmistakable and harder to elide, while _that_ frequently gets worn down to just an extra syllabic bump in the speech stream.

Comment: Would adding a comma after "animals" change the meaning? I believe it is supposed to mean that all the listed items "had suffered greatly" - not only the animals.

Comment: What do you mean we do not use *which* for people? That is not true.  Additionally, neither of those merits the superlative “best” — since you present a dilemma between two alternatives.  As for comparing which of the two is the “better”, this is a matter of dispute; it depends on how neoprescritivist you care to be.

Comment: @user37373: punctuation doesn't change meaning. Punctuation can sometimes signal intonation, which **does** change meaning. Commas are marked by intonation dips, which help the phrase cohere. And _that_ works for everything, so that's why it's more common.

Comment: @tchrist - I was under the impression we don't use "which" for people. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @John Lawler - "Punctuation can sometimes signal intonation, which does change meaning." - That is why I asked. For me, the intonation and the meaning change when we add that comma; as if only the buildings had suffered. Does it not sound different to you?

Comment: Some people have trained themselves as readers to supply the intonation which is not provided by a missing comma between the last two items in a list. Leaving it out is either known as "the Oxford comma" or as not the Oxford comma; I can never remember which is which. But it's a style to leave it out and make the reader reach for it; it's controversial, if you can believe it. I think that's rather silly, but the same is true for most common grammar and usage controversies.

Comment: @John Lawler - That is all very interesting and informative, but does the change in intonation not change the meaning for you? Although, I don't care to push this as it has nothing to do with my original question.

Comment: Change in intonation is like a change in a word; it might make it nonsense or it might make it different. But punctuation is not language; punctuation is technology, and medieval technology at that. It has no more meaning than a gearshift lever, and can't change meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that *buildings* can *suffer,* greatly or otherwise. It is true that you can use *that* with both animate and inanimate objects in a restrictive (aka definining) relative clause, but the verb *suffer* does not collocate, at least not intransitively, with an inanimate object *qua* subject. (This is a little confusing, but when I refer to an *object* in this post I am referring to a *thing* as opposed to either a *person* or *the object of a verb/preposition.*) I *have* seen transitive constructions with inanimate objects *qua* subject, such as *The building suffered great damage from the bombing,* however; but it sounds quite unnatural intransitively. Thus, I suggest rewording the sentence this way:

*He saw people and animals that had suffered greatly, and several/many destroyed/damaged buildings.*

The differences between *several/many* and *destroyed/damaged* would each be a matter of degree.  If the buildings in question have been completely destroyed, to the point of there being nothing left structurally, you could use the adjectives *levelled* or *razed*.

One other alternative for *people and animals that had suffered greatly* would be *wounded/injured people and animals*. The choice between *wounded* and *injured* depends on whether, on the one hand, the harm or injury is caused by combat or some other kind of weapon-related violence, which collocates with *wounded*, or, on the other, an accident of some kind, which usually collocates with *injured*.  (*Injured* can also also collocate with combat or other kinds of weapon-related injuries, so long as the context is clear.) If you want to strengthen *wounded,* change it to *severely wounded*.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think recasting this sentence is the best way to untie this grammar knot. Bravo, Shawn.

Comment: I'm not unhappy about using _suffer_ with an inanimate subject ( **suffer** - get worse; "His grades suffered" : Based on WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection. © 2003-2012 Princeton University) - but using mixed sentient and inanimate subjects with the same verb used literally and metaphorically (taking animate suffering as the root meaning) does sound very awkward.  Of course, the example could easily be tweaked to _He saw people, animals and buildings that all reminded him of his native country_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Easily?  Do you seriously think that "He saw people, animals and buildings that all reminded him of his native country" has even the slightest similarity to "He saw people and animals that had suffered greatly"?  I have more than once been half-asleep at the switch when responding to grammar questions online, but your answer strikes me as a full-monty.  If I, on the other hand, am the one who is half or fully asleep, I will eat my hat, of course.

Comment: @Shawn Moody - I am aware, of course, that buildings don't suffer as we do (intransitively). That's obvious. But the original writer had written a creative piece about returning to his family home after a childhood spent abroad. So I think, in this case, we should give the guy some artistic license and focus on the original question.

Comment: @Shawn Mooney: The key word is **example**: user 37373 was asking about one point of grammar and his example gave rise to a secondary debate (about how the word _suffer_ may legitimately be used). I was saying that his example sentence could be tweaked to avoid the secondary issue, not that the actual sentence could be sensibly rephrased the way I suggested. I'm rather alarmed that you misconstrued my suggestion. It's the whole basis of sensible analysis - tackle one issue at a time as far as possible.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, at the risk of exacerbating your alarm, I still cannot follow you.  Kindly clarify precisely which sentences you were referring to by "his example sentence" and "the actual sentence" in your last post.  I have read every post and every comment on this page, and I cannot find where user37373 has provided an example sentence subsequent to the original sentence in his question, nor do I see any examples anywhere here that talk about someone being reminded of his native country.  Perhaps a comment that would have explained all this was deleted? My hat's here beside me, ready...

Comment: @Shawn Mooney: OP is asking about **Multiple objects + relative clause**, not whether the verb _suffer_ can be used with inanimate referents corresponding to subjects. That is a side-issue, one you seem to have picked up on, and addressed incorrectly. The dictionary reference I quoted has a typical usage of _suffer_ used intransitively and with an inanimate subject referent (_grades_). I did go some way to agreeing, in that using _suffer_ with a compound subject containing both animate and inanimate referents forced the verb into a split-sense duality and was better avoided.

Comment: Substituting the following: **Which would be best / acceptable? "He saw people, animals and buildings THAT / WHICH all reminded him of his native country." As I see it, there are 3 objects: people, animals and buildings. The grammar rules I know state we must use "who with people" but "which with things", etc. And because it is a defining relative clause, I can also use "that". So do the mixed objects (people and things) mean I have to use "that" in this sentence, due to the fact we don't use "which" for people?** would hopefully have restricted analysis to the intended topic.

Answer (score -1):

*He saw people, animals and buildings **that** had suffered greatly.*

Let's unpack your concerns. First, **which** is definitely not the right choice here. I cite [The New York Times' style guide](http://afterdeadline.blogs.nytimes.com/2008/11/24/that-which-or-what/):

> Use that, not which, in a restrictive clause — a clause necessary to the reader’s understanding of the sentence ...

Now, what about saying **who** when people (or animals) are involved? We have had [a good discussion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/how-to-use-who-vs-that) on this site about that already, and it says ***that*** is perfectly fine when referring to any subject, including people.

Finally, what about John Lawler's comment on commas? That'd be the Oxford Comma. Using an extra comma here is not necessary to reduce ambiguity, so I say leave it out. We have had [a long discussion of the merits of said comma](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list) on this site as well.