# Use of that vs who

Tags: relative-pronouns

Is it correct to say 'He is the one that did it' instead of saying 'He is the one who did it' ?

Comment: Why not "He did it"?

Comment: The question is not what is the best way to say it,I am questioning using what in this situation is grammatically correct.

Comment: He is the one that did it, or he is the one who (has) done it. But the second might only apply to mystery novels.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11204/16833

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is grammatical. *That* can have a human antecedent when it introduces a defining relative clause, as it does in your example.