# "That" between "thought" and "could"

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

Is

> It was me that Mr. Jones thought could do it.

correct?

Is *that* required between *thought* and *could*?

Comment: It was **I** that Mr. Jones thought could do it.

Comment: ...being a cleft structure built from 'Mr. Jones thought [that] I could do it'.

Comment: Isn't it either "It's me that" or "It's I who"?

Comment: This is definitely not one for ELL; there's a [Ross Constraint](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/ross.html) involved. Tensed complement clauses are normally not islands, **unless** they're marked with complementizer _that_. Since the relative clause extracts _I_ from the verb phrase _Mr. Jones thought (that) I could do it_, where it's the subject of a complement clause, it's grammatical if _that_ is omitted between _thought_ and _could_, but not if _that_ is present, because extracting a constituent out of an island produces extreme ungrammaticality.

Comment: ... Although the claim that global warming is producing more islands is even more contentious.

Comment: @Kris are you sure about that? Who was it that Mr Jones thought that could do it? Me.

Answer (score 2):

I always thought only the references to inanimate objects use *that* or *which*, otherwise *who* should be used.

> "It was me *who* Mr. Jones thought could do it." - sounds perfectly fine to me. ("Mr. Jones thought I could do it.")

P.S. I intended the text as a comment to an answer above, but cannot comment yet due to the reputation level.

Comment: [Time to change, then.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427/should-you-use-who-or-that-when-talking-about-multiple-people-doing-somethin)

Comment: Yup. Somebody taught you wrong, way back when. There's a lot of that going around.

Answer (score 1):

With a few more changes I think this is even more natural:

> I was the one who Mr. Jones thought could do it.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, a sentence like "It was me thought he could do it" sounds unusual, but (contrary to @johnlawler's statement) not particularly ungrammatical - especially if the word "me" is stressed.

Comment: Of course, one could also say, "'Twas I ..." ;-)