# workers who were sent or workers that were sent?

Tags: that

I am trying to determine the use of "that" or "who" in this sentence: Workers ____ were sent did not speak English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should you use "who" or "that" when talking about multiple people doing something?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427/should-you-use-who-or-that-when-talking-about-multiple-people-doing-somethin) Also [How to use “who” vs. “that”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11204/how-to-use-who-vs-that), and doubtless several others.

Comment: Depends whether the workers are human or bees (or whether you know individual bees and think of them as persons).

Answer (score 2):

With human head nouns it's a **free choice** between *wh*-relatives and *that*-relatives: *Workers who were sent did not speak English* and *Workers that were sent did not speak English* show no semantic differences, and no syntactic differences.