# Which is correct: "staff that may have this information" or "staff who may have this information"?

Tags: relative-pronouns, collective-nouns, animacy, who-that

Should I use 'who' or 'that' in the following sentence?

> Any information you have, or any leads to staff **who** may have this information would be very much appreciated.

> Any information you have, or any leads to staff **that** may have this information would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Were you considering saying what you're talking about? Usually *who* refers to people and *that* refers to everything else. As it stands now, there is a certain gap between your thought process and your written question.

Comment: Either is fine. *Who* is for people and *that* is for both people and objects.

Comment: Wait, your title question refers to the sentence of your post, specifically the word 'who' in that sentence? So your question is *staff who* as opposed to *staff that*?

Comment: Related: [What is the correct relative pronoun for “government”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68790) and linked questions. "That" has a wider range of uses than "which", though, and "who" is replaceable with "that" in many situations, as described here: [How to use “who” vs. “that”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11204)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should you use 'who' or 'that' when talking about multiple people ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427/should-you-use-who-or-that-when-talking-about-multiple-people-doing-somethin); see also [when to use "that" or "who"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/351630/when-to-use-that-or-who)

Comment: To: Mr. Baskin - Yes, that is correct, I wanted to know if "staff who", (as in staff on a hospital unit; I mean specific staff members, not some hypothetical staff members) is better than "staff that". The reason I ask is that Microsoft WORD's spell check tried to change "staff who" to "staff that", without indicating both were correct.  I was taught in high school that "that" refers to things, and CAN refer to groups, but large groups, i.e. a country, a corporation, a broad population.  My "ear" tells me that "staff that" sounds funny. It sounds wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a firm belief in some circles that

- "*Who* refers to people, and *that* refers to things."

Unfortunately, this belief is incorrect, at least in the second part.
As usual, things are more complicated than simple slogans can explain.

*Who* is a *wh-* pronoun, which certainly **does** refer to people, and *only* to people (though this is
true only of *who* and *whom* -- *whose* can refer to **any** possessive noun phrase, human or neuter).

However, *that* is **not** a gendered pronoun; it is a [demonstrative pronoun being used as a

complementizer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73368/15299); demonstrative pronouns can refer to anyone **or** anything.

- *Which/What lollipop do you want? **That** one.*
- *Which/What do you want? **That** lollipop.*
- *Which/What man assaulted you? **That** one.*
- *Who assaulted you? **That** man.*

And, while it is a [complementizer without any meaning and with only a marking job to do, like the *to* of infinitives or the *-ing* of gerunds](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111125/15299), *that* does retain enough of its pronominal status to take the place of the relative *wh*- pronoun.

That is,

- *staff **who** may have this information*
  and
- *staff **that** may have this information*

are both fine and mean the same thing and are correct and conventional and fluent speech. Nobody ever notices the difference. But *that* and *who* never occur together, in either order; choose one.

- **staff **who that** may have this information*
- **staff **that who** may have this information*

In fact, both are frequently omitted when they are not the subject.

That is,

- *staff **who** we talked to*
  and
- *staff **that** we talked to*
  and
- *staff ___ we talked to*

are **also** just fine, equivalent, grammatical, and correct.
(One can also use *whom*, but let's not, OK?)

I suspect the source of this confusion is that the difference between *who* and *that* seems to resemble the difference between *who* and *which* in relative pronouns. Both *who* and *which* are gendered *wh*- pronouns: *who* is for humans, as noted, and *which* is for neuter nouns.

Those who don't know better might apply the *who/which* rule to *who/that*, even though it's wrong.  Any old rule in a storm, apparently.

Comment: Agree completely.

Comment: I think that many Brits would prefer 'staff who we talked to' as sounding less impersonal, whereas 'young men that we talked to' doesn't sound intrinsically impersonal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Can mood influence the preference for one or the other? Interesting ngram - why the inversion? [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28anyone+that+would+have*20%29%2Canyone+who+would+have%2C%28anyone+that+may+have*20%29%2Canyone+who+may+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28anyone%20that%20would%20have%20%2A%2020%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canyone%20who%20would%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28anyone%20that%20may%20have%20%2A%2020%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Canyone%20who%20may%20have%3B%2Cc0)