# We are a group of people who/which/that..?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Which of these three is correct?

- We are a group of people who meet..
- We are a group of people which meets..
- We are a group of people that meets..

This is different from the case when "People" is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: What research have you done on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should you use "who" or "that" when talking about multiple people doing something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/427/should-you-use-who-or-that-when-talking-about-multiple-people-doing-somethin)

Comment: @bookmanu this is different from the case when "people" is the subject of the sentence. (edited)

Answer (score 1):

***We are a group of people who meet..*** is correct where *who* represents *people*, and not *group*.

***We are a group of people which meets..*** would be correct if **a** is replaced with **the** where *which* would represent *group*, and not *people*. Same is the case with the last one.

Comment: What about *that*?

Comment: Same is the case with the last one. I.e. "We are a group of people that meets.." would be correct if 'a' is replaced with 'the' where 'that' would represent group, and not people.

Comment: You use the exact same rule for both 'which' and 'that'!  You are forgetting that 'which' is non-restrictive (adjunct), and 'that' is restrictive (adject).  Which category is 'who'?

Answer (score 0):

We are a group of people who meet.. is correct where who represents people, and not the group.which is for in animated things 
For instance
1. We are the group of people who work hard for the uplift of the society.
in the above sentence who can't be replaced by which because we are talking about people.